# forEach vs (for,while,if,else..) Variable scopes - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Java Script and found a type of function called 'Immediate Functions'. Why we use :

- perform tasks as soon as function is defined
- creating a new variable scope

It is quite confusing that the for , while , if else statements do not create new variable scope but forEach loop do create a new scope. Is there any specific reason behind it? Here are the examples:-

```
var foo = 123;
if (true) {
var foo = 456;// updates the value of global 'foo'
}
console.log(foo); // 456;


let  foo2 = 1111111;
var array = new Array(5).fill(5);
array.forEach(function () {
    let foo2 = 222//creates new variable
    // foo2 = 222//updates global variable
});
console.log('test' + foo2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Read more about Execution context, scope, etc...: https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c

Comment: Using `let` would create a new scope inside `if` block as well. `let` defines a new scope in any block. So does `const`. `var` scope on the other hand is restricted by the surrounding function clause.

Comment: @oniondomes to be clear, using the `let` keyword does not create a new scope, using the `let` keyword only means that the variable created will have block scope only and not function scope as would be the case with the `var` keyword. There is no new scope because `this` does not change, it is still the `this` of the current function scope.

Comment: @sébastien, thanks for pointing out. sorry for operating the terms poorly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `forEach` that creates the new scope, but the `function` that is its argument.  `function` always creates its own `this`.